# How should subpopulations be modelled if I can't discern any difference?

Tags: fixed-effects-model

Every autumn, about 3-7 animals were located and tracked with GPS, and responses $y$ were assembled.

This happened 5 years in a row.

Plotting, I can see some obvious differences between these 5 groups. However, they belong to the very same population of animals.

So, do I model this as a random effect? Or a fixed effect? Or something else?

EDIT:

Data is complex, but here is a part of it:

4 of the 5 groups of animals spend a certain amount of time hunting in a certain area.

The last group spends no amount of time hunting in that area.

The interest could e.g. be in the question "how much time do animals spend hunting in this area, and what are the main effects?".

So now I am considering whether I should include the groups as a main effect, or a random effect. Or maybe include them via a "year", or "time" affect.

Comment: I don't think you have given enough information to allow a useful answer. Is there some hypothesis you want to test? Can you show some of the data?

Comment: A "group" is the set of "3-7 animals" tracked in a particular year? (And "animal" = individual? Also "hunting" came out of nowhere?) There still is not much info here. Would an "effect" be something like territoriality, environmental change (e.g. resource abundance), inter-annual migration, etc.? If groups is a group of individuals, then their locations could be correlated (e.g. a pack/herd).